# Android UI transition not as expected

Tags: android, android-intent, android-animation

I am trying to launch an SMS app (Messenger/Hangouts) from my app. But the UI transition is not as expected. On launch, my app moves to the background and SMS app is launched from below the screen and this transition is slow and very much visible to the user.

I want the transition to be as fast as possible without showing any animation. I tried overridePendingTransition(0,0) and setting the Intent flag (FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION), still does not help.

What should I be doing to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet of code works fine for me:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Please paste the relevant code you have used for the same if the above does not work and I can look into it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Code is like below:
    String uri = "smsto:" + address;
    Intent viewIntent = new Intent();
    viewIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
    viewIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    viewIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

But I pass the context to a different method to start the activity, where the activity is started as below:
context.startActivity(viewIntent);

After that, I casted the context to Activity object and called overridePendingTransition

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: Yes, the issue is still there. I am wondering what could go wrong in this code? The thing is that it is happening only for the SMS app, other apps like FB, Twitter etc are properly transitioned as expected.